# How to use v-if and v-else without any html tag or else

Tags: vue.js

### List item

```
<ul>
 <li>language</li>

   < v-if= "tree()"> //which tag I may use or any other process
    <li>home</li>
    <li>about</li>
   <>
   < v-else> //which tag I may use or any other process
    <li>accounts</li>
    <li>listing</li>
   <>
</ul>'
```

In the `V-if` which html tag i may use or any other `vue.js` process to work with this.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can use [template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt):

```
<template v-if="condition">
</template>
<template v-else>
</template>
```

Template will not be rendered in the browser. But it will parse the contents inside of this to the html.

Comment: @Hasibul- don't forget to accept the answer (the ✔ button next to it) if it has worked for you!

Comment: Would this be possible for component ? Like if I use component as css grid row, it will be encapsulated in div and whole css will break.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use a `<template>` tag inside the `<template>` tag in the component's declaration :/

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect there's actually an answer to this. This is so awesome

Answer (score -7):

you can sometimes use the `<slot>` element to make what you want. Have a look at the slot documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots)

Comment: slot is used for different concept.