# Vue - Bind data conditionally according to property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component that contains a child component which have some property that we can bind to. like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Child :bar="foo"></Child>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  props: ['foo'],
}
</script>
```

Now I want to bind the property 'bar' of the Child component conditionally. For example, I want to bind the property 'bar' of the child component only when the 'foo' property from the parent component is not `undefined`, how can I do that?

---

Update for the guys that advise me to use `v-if` directive:

Using `v-if` directive *ISN'T* an ideal solution, I think. When the conditions get complicated and the number of conditional binding properties get larger (like 5), the cases will grow exponentially and lead to a *VERY LONG* `if-elseif-else` chain. It's ugly, so NO.

I'm wondering if there is a REACT-LIKE way to solve this problem - just working with `vdom` and do binding pragmatically. but I don't know if I can do this in the render function, because I don't discover any API function that can do the same thing as `v-bind` directive on a child component.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Can you not use conditional rendering, ie `v-if="foo"`?

Comment: This sounds very much like an [_XY Problem_](http://xyproblem.info/) where you've already decided what your solution should be without explaining the problem. I can almost guarantee there's a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do

Comment: Please explain the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Stephen.W There's no react like conditional rendering in vue.

Comment: Not sure why I was being downvoted so I removed my answer, but as I pointed out you can create a method that has your long chain of if and else statements and have it return a boolean and you can use that in your v-if statement so it keeps your template clean

Comment: @SmokeyDawson and as mentioned in your now deleted answer, [method calls in templates are very inefficient](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods). A [computed property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) would achieve the same result without the overhead of executing on every tick

Comment: @Phil So according to the link you just posted you change the `methods` keyword to `computed` and have a similar function that returns a boolean

Comment: @SmokeyDawson that's right :) And you treat the computed property as a property instead of a function call, eg `v-if="showChild"` (no parentheses)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `v-if`:

```
<div v-if="foo">
  <Child :bar="foo"></Child>
</div>
<div v-else>
  <Child></Child>
</div>
```

However, I would recommend you not to render conditionally. It's because you can just check the `bar` props is not `undefined`.

---

**Update:**

I have found `v-bind` with object is useful in your case:

```
<Child v-bind="{bar: foo || '' }"></Child>
```

Also, you may try like this - ES6 feature: (But I'm not sure if this works)

```
<Child v-bind="...(foo && {bar: foo})"></Child>
```

Comment: No! This is not a solution. What if there are many (>4) properties that need to be conditional binding? Using `v-if` may just messing things up. Especially when we handling some like *form validation*.

Comment: @Stephen.W Even then you can use `v-if...v-else` using `template`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218040/how-to-use-v-if-and-v-else-without-any-html-tag-or-else/49218055#49218055). Also, you can use `v-if...v-if...v-if...v-if...v-else`

Comment: While your update is inventive, it doesn't achieve what OP _claims_ to want, that being conditional binding. I still have no idea _why_ OP wants to do this though, so nice work