# Vue.js not compatible with CSS Grid tables

Tags: vue.js, css-grid

Is it possible to make Vue compatible with tables generated with CSS Grid?

Here's the problem. To make a table in CSS Grid, you do this:

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto;">
  <div>row 0 col 0</div>
  <div>row 0 col 1</div>
  <div>row 1 col 0</div>
  <div>row 1 col 1</div>
</div>
```

Note that the table cells are direct children of the container. This is a requirement of CSS Grid.

But in Vue, if you want to create a table from some data, you have to do this:

```
<div class="somecontainer">
  <div v-for="item in items">
    <div>{{item.col0}}</div>
    <div>{{item.col1}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the output, each row will be wrapped with a `<div>`:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>row 0 col 0</div>
    <div>row 0 col 1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>row 1 col 0</div>
    <div>row 1 col 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The table cells are not direct children of the container. It appears to be impossible, in Vue, to get rid of the div that wraps the rows, making CSS Grid tables impossible.

I did find some reference to "`display: content`", which could possibly solve the problem in the future, but that is supported only in Firefox at the moment.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `<template v-for>` instead of `<div v-for>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218040/how-to-use-v-if-and-v-else-without-any-html-tag-or-else

Comment: Thanks, both of you. `<template>` does the trick.

Comment: Would this be possible for component ? Like if I use component as css grid row, it will be encapsulated in div and whole css will break.